# FME - calculating distance to points along a line

Tags: distance, fme-form, length

I am new to FME, and trying to get my head around what should be pretty straightforward issues, but I find myself going around in circles

Basically I want to determine the distance (chainage) to a series of points on a water main, which consists of 8 connecting line segments.

I have managed to create the chain of points every 10m by using the Labeller and then the GeometryCoercer (fme_point).
I also joined up the 8 line segments into 1 by using LineJoiner.

The question is now how do I get the chainage to each of the points along the line?

- I've tried MeasureGenerator, but that gives me the chainage to the vertices not to the points
- I've tried ShortestPathFinder but they all come out of the Unused port. I also tried it with the TopologyBuilder first, but this had no effect
- I've tried PointOnLineOverlayer but this splits my line.
- I checked [FME - Calculate distance of point along a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30518/fme-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line) but couldn't get the answer either.

I think I'm close, but anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30518/fme-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line

Comment: I think we'd need to see a bit more of the source data to help (in particular I'm not clear on the difference between the vertices and the points). You could also send the workspace/data to Safe Support for us to look at (http://www.safe.com/supportrequest). Mark it FAO Mark Ireland and it'll be assigned to me.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've sent you an email with the workspace and data attached.